# MongoDB - $match based on another field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get results like simple inner join from SQL, for get all accounts of the same id_customer.
I almost do this, but I get something like left join, and I don't now how to filer the result of query.

query:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": { $gte: 41000 }
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "department",
            localField: "ID",
            foreignField: "ACCOUNT.ID_CUSTOMER",
            as: "customer"
        }
    },
    { $match: { "myArray": { $ne: [] } } },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$customer",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        $unwind: "$customer.ACCOUNT"
    },
    {
            $match: {
                "customer.ACCOUNT.ID_CUSTOMER": "$ID" 
            }
    },

])
```

actual result:

```
empty
```

expected result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfccc28d29876c2988c7c05"), 
    "ID" : 4.0, 
    "SECOND_NAME" : "abc", 
    "FIRST_NAME" : "abc", 
    "ID_DISCOUNT" : {
        "ID" : 3.0, 
        "TITLE" : "abc", 
        "AMOUNT" : 5.0
    }, 
    "LOAN" : {
        "ID" : 4.0, 
        "AMOUNT" : 42750.0
    }, 
    "customer" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb7f8f5861584bbaedf718"), 
        "ID" : 1.0, 
        "TITLE" : "abc", 
        "ADDRESS" : "abc", 
        "CITY" : "abc", 
        "ACCOUNT" : {
            "ID" : 10.0, 
            "ID_CUSTOMER" : 4.0, 
            "DATE_OPEN" : "2019-09-24 21:03:44"
        }
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfccc28d29876c2988c7c05"), 
    "ID" : 4.0, 
    "SECOND_NAME" : "abc", 
    "FIRST_NAME" : "abc ", 
    "ID_DISCOUNT" : {
        "ID" : 3.0, 
        "TITLE" : "abc", 
        "AMOUNT" : 5.0
    }, 
    "LOAN" : {
        "ID" : 4.0, 
        "AMOUNT" : 42750.0
    }, 
    "customer" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb7f8f5861584bbaedf718"), 
        "ID" : 1.0, 
        "TITLE" : "abc", 
        "ADDRESS" : "abc", 
        "CITY" : "abc", 
        "ACCOUNT" : {
            "ID" : 11.0, 
            "ID_CUSTOMER" : 4.0, 
            "DATE_OPEN" : "2019-08-23 21:03:44"
        }
    }
}
```

List of all account with the same id_customer, but

```
$match: {
                    "customer.ACCOUNT.ID_CUSTOMER": "$ID" 
                }
```

not doing what I want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution: use $expr operator

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": { $gte: 41000 }
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "department",
            localField: "ID",
            foreignField: "ACCOUNT.ID_CUSTOMER",
            as: "customer"
        }
    },
    { $match: { "myArray": { $ne: [] } } },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$customer",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        $unwind: "$customer.ACCOUNT"
    },
    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$customer.ACCOUNT.ID_CUSTOMER", "$ID"] } } },

])
```